# Using a Data Model to 'relate' to other models (create relationships)

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uicollectionview, related-content

I have a data model that stores specific extreme-sports information. This data is displayed in a tableView, where the cells (extreme sport tricks) can be tapped to view all the details in a Details VC. Part of these details is an optional 'related' section, which can be defined as part of the model.

Example - Table Cell may read "Kickflip" (a skateboarding trick). I can associate "Ollie" and "360-flip" (two more skateboarding tricks) to the Kickflip model's related section.

I want these two related terms (Ollie and 360-flip) clickable so that instead of the user reading 'Kickflip' details, they can read the definition of either Ollie or 360-flip.

**My question here is how can I get the 'related' items to refresh the data to the specific term.**

Here is my model:

```
struct ExtremeSportsData {
    static func getAllSportsTerms() -> [ExtremeSportsTermsWithSectionHeaders] {
        return [
            ExtremeSportsTermsWithSectionHeaders(sectionName: "A", sectionObjects: [
                ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Acid Drop", definition: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", relatedTerms: nil),
                ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Alpha Flip", definition: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", relatedTerms: nil),
                ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Axle Stall", definition: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", relatedTerms: ["Ollie"])
                ]),
            ExtremeSportsTermsWithSectionHeaders(sectionName: "O", sectionObjects: [
                ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Ollie", definition: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", relatedTerms: ["Shuvit"]),
                ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Overturn", definition: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", relatedTerms: ["Acid Drop", "Alpha Flip"])
                ]),
            ExtremeSportsTermsWithSectionHeaders(sectionName: "S", sectionObjects: [
                ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Shuvit", definition: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", relatedTerms: ["Ollie", "Axle Stall", "Overturn"])
                ])
        ]
    }
}
```

Once a cell is tapped, the information on the DetailVC gets displayed in a Collection View. I want the related terms (if there are any!) to update the data to that specific term. As you can see in my data above - if the user taps on Ollie, they will have Shuvit as a related term. That can be clicked to read the Shuvit definition & information.

My thought process for the UI was to use Contains(String), however this solution does not work IF there is a typo in the data.. (and my code below is not perfect)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let specificRelatedTerm = receivedSportTerm!.relatedTerms![indexPath.item]
    if receivedSportTerm!.term.contains(specificRelatedTerm) {
        print("Yes - Related")
    }
    else {
        print("No - Not related")
    }
}
```

How can I set up "relationships" between data, so that I can tap buttons in a UI to update information based on the relationships?

I will be happy to clarify any of the above... Something is telling me I did not word this as good as I could have, but any help is appreciated thank you.

[image: UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some sort of class like `Repository` or `Holder` will be good for this option. Basic idea - you have `Repository` that contains all `ExtremeSportsTermsModel`s and related items for each `ExtremeSportsTermsModel` and `func`s that can manupilate with data.

```
final class RelatedFlipsRepository {

    enum Action {
        case add
        case remove
    }

    private var relations: [String: Set<String>] = [:]
    var flips: [ExtremeSportsTermsModel] = []

    init(flips: [ExtremeSportsTermsModel]) {
        self.flips = flips
    }

    // MARK: - Public

    func addFlip(_ flip: ExtremeSportsTermsModel, relatedTo related: [ExtremeSportsTermsModel] = []) {
        if !flips.contains(where: { $0.term == flip.term }) {
            flips.append(flip)
        }

        configureRelated(related, flip: flip, action: .add)
    }

    func getRelated(to flip: ExtremeSportsTermsModel) -> [ExtremeSportsTermsModel] {
        guard let values = relations[flip.term], !values.isEmpty else { return [] }
        return flips.filter({ values.contains($0.term) })
    }

    func configureRelated(_ related: [ExtremeSportsTermsModel], flip: ExtremeSportsTermsModel, action: Action) {
        switch action {
        case .add:
            addRelated(related, to: flip)
            related.forEach({ addRelated([flip], to: $0) })

        case .remove:
            removeRelated(related, from: flip)
            related.forEach({ removeRelated([flip], from: $0) })
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func addRelated(_ related: [ExtremeSportsTermsModel], to flip: ExtremeSportsTermsModel) {
        if !related.isEmpty {
            let relatedValues = related.map({ $0.term })
            if let values = relations[flip.term] {
                relations[flip.term] = values.union(relatedValues)
            } else {
                relations[flip.term] = Set(relatedValues)
            }
        }
    }

    private func removeRelated(_ related: [ExtremeSportsTermsModel], from flip: ExtremeSportsTermsModel) {
        guard let values = relations[flip.term], !related.isEmpty else { return }
        relations[flip.term] = values.subtracting(related.map({ $0.term }))
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let ollie = ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Ollie")
let shuvit = ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Shuvit")
let acidDrop = ExtremeSportsTermsModel(term: "Acid Drop")

let repository = RelatedFlipsRepository(flips: [ollie, shuvit, acidDrop])

repository.configureRelated([acidDrop, shuvit], flip: ollie, action: .add)
print(repository.getRelated(to: ollie)) // [Shuvit, Acid Drop]
print(repository.getRelated(to: acidDrop)) // [Ollie]

repository.configureRelated([acidDrop], flip: ollie, action: .remove)
print(repository.getRelated(to: ollie)) // [Shuvit]
print(repository.getRelated(to: acidDrop)) // []
```

As you can see `Repository` have two properties `relations` and `flips` (nobody said that you have to keep all data in one property, right?). `relations` has type `[String: Set<String>]` that keeps `ExtremeSportsTermsModel`'s `term` values as the "primary keys" and it's not really good. In most cases there is an `let id: Int` value or something close to it, maybe you should think about it too.

This workflow can help you to take care about related data in both directions, but if you want more specific solution you can use [`Graph`](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Graph) data structure, but it's not quite easy to implement and support.

P.S. Copy/paste [`file`](https://pastebin.com/JBzp0xzN).

---

`didSelectItemAt` problem.

I think you strategy should be like 1) grab tapped `relatedItem`, 2) set the `relatedItem` to `item` value by which `ViewController` can reload yourself, 3) and call appropriate func to reload UI.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let relatedItem = repository.getRelated(to: receivedSportItem!)[indexPath.row]
    // set `relatedItem` to you `item`
    // call `reloadUI` func
}
```

Comment: I won't be able to try this until later, just wanted to give you a preemptive thank you for your help! I will touch base later :)

Comment: I now how my UI all set up! I modified your above code a bit, but the relationships are there, and the related data is properly updating. How would I handle the tapping of the "related" CV cells to update the UI? This is where I was stuck in the "didSelectItemAt" in my original post.   Additionally, I am defining all my terms in the main VC viewDidLoad method... I'm guessing I should keep the data in its own class?

Comment: Hi, @Joe. I little bit stuck with your questions. Maybe you can share some screenshots or github code (or so). This will be very helpful to understand the problem at this point.

Comment: Sure! I added a screenshot to original question. All the data (term title, term definition, related terms) is properly displaying in the Detail VC. I would just like the related terms cells clickable, so they reload the data depending on what term was tapped. (The related terms is a Collection View.) I made an attempt in my above question in didSelectItemAt, however, this does not seem like a good approach.